Doubt regarding directional derivative
I am reading a book called "Vector Analysis" by P.R. Ghosh and J.G.Chakravorty.
In it it is stated that-
'Consider a scalar point function $f(r)$ or $f(x,y,z)$ in the neighbourhood of the point $P_{0}(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$ of position vector $r_{0}$, where it is continuous and differentiable.A straight line through $P_{0}$ in the direction of the unit vector $e$= ($\cos$a,$\cos$b,$\cos$c has the the vector equation $r= r_{0}+ se$ where the scalar s is the magnitude of vector $PP_{0}$
The parametric equations of the straight line are
$x= x_{0}+ scos a$, (likewise for others)
Along the line, $f(x,y,x)$ is a function of a alone and we have
$$\frac{df}{ds} = \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}\frac{dx}{ds} + \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}\frac{dy}{ds}+\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}}\frac{dz}{ds} \quad\quad(1) $$
My question is:-
(1) How the authors derived the eq(1)?
I tried to think about it but I can't find anything.
Any help?
Edit: The answer by @Ninja Darth is helpful.The answer arises a question which is why we can write 'dw' as mentioned in the answer. Any proof?
Edit 2: Still looking forward for better explanation.

The Differential Of A Function. The "d" operator, itself, is a core part of formalism for Differentiable Manifolds, that gives rise to The Exterior Derivative and Differential Forms. In particular, the equations and computations used can be treated as those for differential forms.

I think this may help.

As a function $w = f(x,y,z)$ of $(x,y,z)$, we may write
$$dw = \frac{∂w}{∂x} dx + \frac{∂w}{∂y} dy + \frac{∂w}{∂z} dz.$$
As functions $x = g(s)$, $y = h(s)$, $z = k(s)$ of $s$, we may write
$$dx = \frac{dx}{ds} ds,\quad dy = \frac{dy}{ds} ds,\quad dz = \frac{dz}{ds} ds.$$
Applying the chain rule to the function $w = F(s) = f(g(s), h(s), k(s))$ means substituting for $dx$, $dy$ and $dz$ in the relation for $dw$:
$$\begin{align}
dw
&= \frac{∂w}{∂x} \frac{dx}{ds} ds + \frac{∂w}{∂y} \frac{dy}{ds} ds + \frac{∂w}{∂z} \frac{dz}{ds} ds\\
&= \left(\frac{∂w}{∂x} \frac{dx}{ds} + \frac{∂w}{∂y} \frac{dy}{ds} + \frac{∂w}{∂z} \frac{dz}{ds}\right) ds,
\end{align}$$
thereby yielding the corresponding differential coefficient:
$$\frac{dw}{ds} = \frac{∂w}{∂x} \frac{dx}{ds} + \frac{∂w}{∂y} \frac{dy}{ds} + \frac{∂w}{∂z} \frac{dz}{ds}.$$
Written in terms of the functions, themselves:
$$F'(s) = f_x(g(s), h(s), k(s)) g'(s) + f_y(g(s), h(s), k(s)) h'(s) + f_z(g(s), h(s), k(s)) k'(s).$$
